# Remove port 8080 from URL on IIS 10

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have an IPFS services running on port 8080 and can currently access it when I include port 8080 in the url:

[http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/ipfs/{IpfsHash}](http://www.mywebsite.com:8080/ipfs/%7BIpfsHash%7D)

I also have 2 rules that deal with redirecting non http requests to https and another one redirecting non-www to www. How can I add another rule that will redirect request above to

[https://www.mywebsite.com/ipfs/{IpfsHash}](https://www.mywebsite.com/ipfs/%7BIpfsHash%7D)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Redirection cannot hide the port number for you. You have to host that IPFS service at port 80 and 443 to get rid of the port number, or set up reverse proxy rules to forward traffic from port 80/443 to port 8080.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by Lex Li. You will not be able to remove the port 8080. You need to use the default ports 80 and 443 to remove the port number from the URL.